# I'm getting tautological compiler errors. How am I supposed to fix "argument of type "X" is incompatible with parameter of type "X"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, vulkan, amd-gpu

The specific details in my case: I'm using MSVC with [AMD's vulkan memory allocator](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator/blob/master/src/vk_mem_alloc.h), which is a stb-style single header file. (So you include it in your project like:

```
#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"
```

within a single compilation unit to compile it, and just

```
#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"
```

in any file that needs to use it.)

Anyways:

Some examples of specific errors I'm getting are:

> argument of type "VmaDeviceMemoryBlock *" is incompatible with parameter of type "VmaDeviceMemoryBlock *"

and

> a value of type "VmaSuballocationType" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "VmaSuballocationType"

and

> declaration is incompatible with "void VmaBlockMetadata::PrintDetailedMap_Allocation(VmaJsonWriter &json, VkDeviceSize offset, VmaAllocation hAllocation) const"

when the definition is

```
void VmaBlockMetadata::PrintDetailedMap_Allocation(class VmaJsonWriter& json,
    VkDeviceSize offset,
    VmaAllocation hAllocation) const
```

These errors, as well as many others that aren't obviously broken, absolutely litter the file. Even stranger, I can build the program and it compiles and runs without issue. Its populating of my error window with this noise is totally undermining the error window's usefulness. I'm also now getting other strange errors throughout my code, and I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular library but i wonder if including (or not) that macro preceding the include is breaking the One Definition Rule somehow? And attempting to cause two different types with the same name? Though I'd expect a different compilation error if that were the case.

Comment: Can you post or link the complete error output, and perhaps a sample source file that demonstrates the problem (i.e. [mcve])?

Comment: I don't believe so- these kinds of files are essentially `library.h >> #ifdef LIBRARY_IMPLEMENTATION >> library.c >> #endif`, so the definitions ("in the metaphorical c file") are only seen from the single compilation unit which #defined LIBRARY_IMPLEMENTATION before including it. (Which I have double checked that I have so done)

Comment: I'm using VMA with MSVC in a largish project with no problems (from VMA.) And since you seem to be correctly handling the most prevalent case of bizarre errors (#defining the IMPL macro in more places than one,) I have two questions (but I'm not hopeful that either would lead to anything.) 1: Are you sure that you have #defined the IMPL macro in a source file (not a header file,) and *after* all the other #includes? and 2: Are you sure that you don't have circular inclusion, or unity build or other weird setup that would lead to circular inclusion?

Comment: If the program builds, then it's an IDE problem.

Comment: Yeah @Phildo, what's up with that? Does it compile/link/run or not?

Comment: yes, it does compile/link/run (or at least, it has in the past, where I ignored these errors _because_ they weren't causing compilation problems...). But now I'm in the middle of a nasty refactor, and these errors are getting in the way, so I can't test that it compiles in my current project due to those errors. I'm working on putting together a minimal visual studio project that repros this, but now I can't even get it to link correctly w/ vulkan. so tl;dr: I'm working on it. that said: if it IS an "IDE problem", how do I fix it? (I assumed Visual Studio 2019 was battle tested as anything...)

Comment: ok: my linker issues w/ the minimal project were because I didn't select to build for 64 bit (I'm new to Visual Studio. Very frustrated.). Now that I've built a minimal project using vk_mem_alloc.h, I am NOT able to reproduce the above errors. Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Clearly your attempt at a minimal reproducible example isn't minimal enough.  You'd debug it the same way you'd debug any other bug that fails to reproduce in a smaller example: you try to isolate the cause by subtracting code from your reproducible case to progressively transform it into your smaller case until it no longer reproduces.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact same set of errors using visual studio 2019. The error in my case was using uniform initialization with an implicit cast.

I needed to change

```
uint32_t uniformOffset{ pad_uniform_buffer_size(sizeof(GPUSceneData)) * frameIndex };
```

to

```
uint32_t uniformOffset{ static_cast<uint32_t>(pad_uniform_buffer_size(sizeof(GPUSceneData)) * frameIndex) };
```

because pad_uniform_buffer_size returns `size_t` and I was trying to implicity cast it to `uint32_t` with uniform initialization.

I have no idea why the error manifested itself in that vma file, but this was the solution in my case.